# django rest PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=App.objects.all()) is not JSON serializabl

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have some nested serializers, and I'm going to get the users objects in a JSON format through http requests, using following snippet:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/users',
                 auth=("admin", "mat"))
```

But here is what it returns:

```
PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=App.objects.all()) is not JSON serializabl
```

I tried a lot of approached include using `to_representation` method and inheriting from `serializers.RelatedField`. But always I get the same result.

It seems that I'm doing something wrong. I'd be appreciate if you have any suggestion regarding this?

Here are serializers:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',
                  'popularity')


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('en_name',
                  'fa_name',
                  'tags')


class CpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CP
        fields = ('en_name',
                  'fa_name',
                  'id_number')


class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    cp = CpSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = App
        fields = ('en_name',
                  'fa_name',
                  'package_name',
                  'build_number',
                  'downloads',
                  'cp',
                  'category')


class UserAppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserApps
        app =  AppSerializer() # or even serializers.StringRelatedField()
        fields = ('status', 'user_rate', 'comment', 'app')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return None


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    id_number = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='userprofile.id_number')
    apps = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'password',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'email',
                  'id_number',
                  'apps')

    def get_apps(self, obj):
        if obj.username != "admin":
            return
        else:
            apps = UserAppSerializer(read_only=True,
                                     many=True)
            return apps


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'id_number')
```

And here is the `get` method of my view:

```
def get(self, request):
    print("call get method on {}".format(self.__class__.__name__))
    if request.user.username == 'admin':
        users = User.objects.all()
        lookup_field = 'username'
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I've defined the `apps` field in `UserProfile` as following:

```
apps = models.ManyToManyField('UserApps')
```

And in `UserApps` the `app` as following:

```
app = models.ManyToManyField(Application)
```

And in `Application` the `cp` and `category` as:

```
cp = models.ForeignKey('cp.CP')
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

And in `category` the `tags` has been defined as:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_apps(self, obj):
    if obj.username != "admin":
        return
    else:
        apps = UserAppSerializer(read_only=True,
                                 many=True)
        return apps
```

This function is incorrect.
that function is getting user instance as parameter `obj` and is supposed to return value for `app` field.
However the function doesn't do anything with the user instance and instead of returning value return an empty instance of UserAppSerializer.

also
`app = models.ManyToManyField(Application)`
This should've been called `apps` for clarity
`apps = models.ManyToManyField(Application)`

Then your serializer function can be re-written like this

```
def get_apps(self, obj):
    if obj.username != "admin":
        return
    else:
        return UserAppSerializer(instance=obj.apps, 
                                 read_only=True, many=True).data
```